# Why we should inject CSS with CSS modules and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I heard that we should use CSS modules and inject the CSS to our page so that load time of the page is faster.

Actually I'm using pug with server side rendering and injecting the CSS in the head with javascript.

I don't even use fully css modules cause the class names get rendered by the server since it is not a spa.

Why i should inject the css what are the benefits, I mean then i will have a huge js file, that is not worse?

and Why the docs say:

> For production builds it's recommended to extract the CSS from your bundle being able to use parallel loading of CSS/JS resources later on.

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#extracts-css-into-separate-files

I mean it is not better to extract them from the beginning?